# is there a way to pin an element with framer-motion in a gsap manner?

Tags: reactjs, gsap, framer-motion

I'm wondering if there is a way, and how can it be achieved, to pin an element in a `gsap` manner but with FRAMER MOTION. In order to do something just like that :

https://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/pen/LYpaPQp

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Wondering the same, did you end up figuring this out?